# Heroku saves postgres databases?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I am using heroku with nodejs but heroku reset database when server closed. I am using free version of heroku. When heroku server is close (heroku closing servers when there is no activity about 30 mins). And If ı understand right heroku supports postgres databases. Is heroku close postgres databases in shutdown?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

No, only files like images are removed after 30min, database is not being removed.

Comment: I am sure after 30 minutes heroku reset my database

Comment: Maybe your database is too big? Heroku has limit on free version.

Comment: My file have one table and 2 columns in it. and there is 4 values. I made a register and login screen. When I register a value. I can do it succesfully and I can verify registered in login. But when server reseted. I cant find my registered value

Comment: And you have only 1 app on Heroku, don't you?